# How to find blank cells in excel using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Im new to pandas so i dont know if this is a dumb question to ask or not.

How can i make an if statement detect a blank cell and run a code if true.

Ex.

```
if (blank_cell_found):
    execute_code
```

I tried using if cell is None but im not getting a response from my if statement.

Im using an array to store the pandas column, i know that there's probably a better way to do this but like i said im new to this.

So lets say my excel sheet looks like this:

```
  A          B              
Name1    LastName1                       
Name2                  
Name3    LastName3                  
Name4    LastName4
```

My code:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('File.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')

LastName = df['B'].values

for Array in LastName:
    if Array is None:
        print('Cell is empty')
```

When i run this i expect to get a response in the concole but dont get any.

I tried `Array == ""` and `Array == LastName[1]` to see if i would get anything but still no response.

If there is a simpler way to do this that would be appreciated too.

Comment: Try using `if pandas.isna(Array)`, which btw, is quite inefficient way of doing it. What is your expected output? Just print `Cell is empty` as many times as there is empty cells?

Comment: currently im just trying to trigger my if statement, the `Cell is empty` for now is just a placeholder. 
What i want to do is:
`if (cell is empty):` 

        `drop index`

Comment: _drop index_ as in drop the entire row if any cell is empty? How about just `df.dropna(subset='B')`?

Comment: No i want to keep the column.
What i want to remove any row that has incomplete data

Comment: `df.dropna(subset=['B'])` will do exactly that. `subset` here is used as a criteria. In other words, row is dropped if and only if cell of column `B` is empty: if row has an empty cell in column `A`, `dropna(subset=['B'])` will not drop anything.

Comment: Could you show an example of it using my example code, if its no trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, OP wants to drop **rows** if there's empty cell (i.e. `NaN` in pandas).

Using modified version from OP's sample data (Note I added last row where column `A` has empty cell, too):

```
print(df)
       A          B
0  Name1  LastName1
1  Name2        
2  Name3  LastName3
3  Name4  LastName4
4         LastName5
```

Using `df.dropna()` will drop **any** row if any corresponding column has empty cell:

```
       A          B
0  Name1  LastName1
2  Name3  LastName3 <<< row 1 is dropped 
3  Name4  LastName4 <<< row 4 is dropped
```

Using `df.dropna(subset=['B'])` will drop **only** if column `B` has empty cell:

```
       A          B
0  Name1  LastName1
2  Name3  LastName3 <<< row 1 is dropped since (2, 'B') was empty
3  Name4  LastName4
4    NaN  LastName5 <<< row 4 is not dropped since dropna is only looking at 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks for example i get it now.

Also do you any places i can read up on pandas to get a better understanding of it?

Comment: @JohnZapanta pandas has a great page for learners. Check [Tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html) and [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#min)

Answer (score 4):

if your cell in excel is totally empty then print the Array variable will output a 'nan'. so if it contains nan then check:

```
import pandas as pd

if pd.isnull(Array):
```

if the above one is not working then there might be spaces, so try:

```
if Array.strip() == "":
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using isnan() function from numpy library

```
import numpy as np

for Array in LastName:
    if np.isnan(Array):
        print('Cell is empty')
```